# React filter and map issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "results":[
       {
          "fullName":"Nick Andrew Mandela",
          "lastName":"Mandela",
          "specialties":[
             "Vein Care Again",
             "Neurology"
          ],
          "url":"#",
          "image":"../images/avatar.png",
          "gender":"Male",
          "bio": "",
          "locations":[
             {
                "name":"St Louis",
                "url":"https://www.google.com",
                "streetAddress":null,
                "cityStateZip":null,
                "lat":0,
                "lng":0,
                "distance":0.8122855139943341,
                "phone":null,
                "image":null,
                "availability":null
             },
             {
                "name":"Olathe",
                "url":"https://www.google.com",
                "streetAddress":null,
                "cityStateZip":null,
                "lat":0,
                "lng":0,
                "distance":23.1210731921023,
                "phone":null,
                "image":null,
                "availability":null
             },
             {
                "name":"Vein Care Center",
                "url":"https://www.google.com",
                "streetAddress":null,
                "cityStateZip":null,
                "lat":0,
                "lng":0,
                "distance":12.59373900731615,
                "phone":null,
                "image":null,
                "availability":null
             }
          ]
       },
```

the "results" property obviously has more than 1 child element.
I'm working in Next.js, so JavaScript.  Some items list the gender as Male, others as Female and still others as null.  I want to dynamically filter the JSON so I can say, pull only 'Male' items.  I have the filter in place, it will return the correct number of items in the map, but when I print them out, say 2 items, it's not printing the correct 2 items.

For instance, if I do this:

```
console.log(doctors.results.filter(r => r.gender === 'Male').sort((a, b) => a.locations[0].distance - b.locations[0].distance));
```

the console displays 2 items and they are the correct 2 items.

But when I do this:

```
Object.keys(doctors.results.filter(r => r.gender === 'Male').sort((a, b) => a.locations[0].distance - b.locations[0].distance)).map((key) => (
                    <div key={key}>
                      {doctors.results[key].fullName} - {doctors.results[key].gender}
                      </div>
                  ))}
```

It will print out only 2 items, but they will not be the right items.  1 is a Male and 1 is a Female.  I hope this makes sense...

Comment: why you are using `Object.keys()` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you had a small example code sandbox where we can see the issue in action.

Comment: Why are you not just mapping inline (`.filter().sort().map()`)? Why filter and sort and run it through `Object.keys`, then map it?

Comment: both array.filter and array.sort will return array and you can map in that no need `Object.keys()`

Comment: Yes it looks like the way you then call `doctors.results[key].fullName` might be causing the issue.

Comment: oh man... you are all freaking geniuses.... Why did I not ask this questions 24 hours ago??  So ya, removing the Object.keys part and then stringing together the .filter().sort().map() has solved the problem completely.  Then instead of doctors.results[key].fullName, I can just call doctor.fullName.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above, I changed this:

```
{Object.keys(doctors.results.filter(r => r.gender === 'Male').sort((a, b) => a.locations[0].distance - b.locations[0].distance)).map((key) => (
                    <div key={key}>
                      {doctors.results[key].fullName} - {doctors.results[key].gender}
                      </div>
                  ))}
```

to this:

```
{doctors.results
                  .sort((a, b) => a.locations[0].distance - b.locations[0].distance)
                  .filter(r => r.gender === 'Male')
                  .map((doctor) => (
                    <div>
                      {doctor.fullName} - {doctor.gender}
                      </div>
                  ))}
```

Now it correctly displays 2 items and they are the right 2 items.